# php script running on apache

Tags: php, apache, cron

hello I have a question and would like to know if it is possible to make running a rule in apache with a php script.
I will give an example
let's say I want to delete images that have more than 1 year registered in the database.
then I make a script right? gives leaves it running in apache this check with an interval of 5 minutes?

Comment: The question is hard to understand. Can you show some code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Apache doesn't do scheduling. You'll want something like cron

Comment: Linux, windows or mac ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, but most probably you want to run this script in Cron, not in Apache.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

There are several reasons *not* to use Apache:

- With Apache, script will be executed on client's request. You never know when the next request is going to happen -- maybe in 5 minutes, maybe in two years.
- Once script is started, your client will have to wait until the script has finished; this will needlessly increase page load time.

Answer (score 1):

To run a script by itself, you use

```
php file.php
```

in the command line. To make it run every x often, you use [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), which you access via command line most of the time with the command

```
crontab -e
```

But all of this assumes you have access to command line on your server. If you don't, it might be best to just use [Require once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) to include the script at the top of every page, so that it's run every time someone loads your site

Comment: Not in all cases. To run from a Cronjob you will need to include the PHP location `/usr/local/php` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Apache it's self doesn't handle automation/scheduling, there is another linux technology available for you to perform a task like this.

---

**Reasons To Use Cron over apache**

- Does Not Support automation/timed requests
- Events will be made on user request (when navigating to your php
  script)
- Once the user navigates away from the current page, the current
  executing script will stop

**Why Use Cronjobs?**
 - Cron Supports timed events
 - Does not require any user requests (runs automated)
 - Carries out the script until it has finished executing
 - Control the output, *You can control the output to push into a text
   file for logging or go to /dev/null to destroy all output*

**Down Sides To Cron?**

There typically is no downsides to cronjobs, rather an annoyance is that in a server envrionment, cron will attempt to E-mail any output (echo, print, print_r, var_dump or any HTML) to the `root` alias

---

This is called a `cron job` usually referred to as a `cron` what this does, is essentially like `Windows Task Scheduler` where it runs a task in the parameters that you wish for example.. *Time*.

Following this text is a basic entry for a cronjob and how to access this.

If you are accessing via `cpanel` then there should be an option near the bottom of the task lists. How to create one using cpanel is explained within the page it's self.

---

Editing from Command line:

*Use your favorite text editor in this case I will use nano.. I am running as root*

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

You will be then presented with a basic input (unless modified)

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

---

Add the following line (modify to meet your requirements) this one will run every minute.

```
* * * * *  root /usr/bin/php /var/www/cron.php # This will run every minute as the root user
```

*Layout*

`* * * * *` -  represent the time, in this case.. Every minute, of every hour, of every day, of every month of every week

`root` - This is the user the cron will run as

`/usr/bin/php` - For compatability reasons you should include the path to where PHP is installed too

`/var/www/cron.php`  - Location of the PHP script to execute based on the time stated

---

The setup for a cronjob:

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

Using what I have shown/explained with the diagram above this section of text, modify your crontab to meet your requirements

---

If using a Mac setup, then follow this post:

[Getting started with cronjobs on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683620/getting-started-with-cronjobs-on-a-mac)

**Good Luck**