# OSX Cron When Connected to Internet

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, cron, vps

How can I run a script every day on OSX when I am connected to the internet?

The script fetches backup files form my VPS and downloads them locally.

What is the correct way to set this up and run it on OSX?

Comment: You can write a script add to your local crontab. Using scp to copy backups files every day from vps to your machine.

Comment: @LeeHoYo I don't know what you mean. Right now I have an rsync script that does it but it isn't automated to happen every day.

Comment: add it to the `crontab`. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting started with cronjobs on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683620/getting-started-with-cronjobs-on-a-mac)